# Defining a Subspace to Match a Basis

Tags: matrices

Let $B = \{(1,2,1),(2,2,1)\}$ Find $a,b,c \in R$ such that $B$ is a basis for the subspace:

$$S = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\ | \ ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=0 \} $$

I tried creating a basis from $S$ and got $ (-b/a,1,0)$ and $ (-c/a,0,1) $ but I can not see how that can be changed to fit the form of $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $(1,2,1),(2,2,1)\in S$. In other words, you have to find $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+2b+c=0\\2a+2b+c=0\end{array}\right.$$But this means that $a=0$ and that $c=-2b$. So, take, for instance, $a=0$, $b=1$, and $c=-2$. Then $S$ is $2$-dimensional and, since $(1,2,1)$ and $(2,2,1)$ are linearly independent, $\bigl\{(1,2,1),(2,2,1)\bigr\}$ is a basis of $S$.